# Gannt chart with Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

I'm struggling with Gannt charts to replace months with Quarters (for having a more compact view). The question was previously asked here but I couldn't identify a proper answer. Any ideas?

A second point is that I'd like to add "milestones" (like M1, M2..) that are made explicit somewhere else in the text (M1 = first achievement)

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}
\newcommand\ganttbarbis[5]{\ganttbar{#1}{#3}{#4}\ganttbar[inline, bar/.append style={fill=#5},bar label font=\footnotesize]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, 
vgrid={dotted,draw=none,draw=none}, %hgrid=true, 
x unit=0.45cm,  % NOTE: width for a single month
y unit chart = 0.6cm, bar height=0.6,
y unit title = 0.5cm, title height=1,
include title in canvas=false,
time slot unit=month
]{2023-09}{2025-10}  
% temporal marks
\gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=black!30,draw=black}]{year} \\
\gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=black!20,draw=black}]{month} \\
% horizontal bars
\ganttbarbis{WP~0}{Project coordination}{2023-10}{2025-09}{blue!50} \\
\ganttbarbis{WP~1}{WP1 #1}{2023-10}{2025-02}{red!50} \\
\ganttbarbis{WP~2}{WP2 #2}{2025-01}{2025-06}{red!25} \\   
% not a very nice Milestone - how to add explanations of M1?
\ganttmilestone{M1}{2024-10}\\
\end{ganttchart}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to show a minimum working example that demonstrates the issue from `\documentclass{}\begin{document}\end{document}`.

Comment: Edited, thanks for pointing out